# PyQt5 closeEvent: How do I use it correctly?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I have a thread running in my GUI, which I want to close properly, when the user clicks the "X". "Try to use the closeEvent!", I thought, but as it turns out this isn't that easy for me.
I tried several things, that I found here on stackoverflow, but nothing works for me.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import threading


class Ui_MainWindow(object):   # I also tried QtWidgets.QMainWindow, makes no difference

     def __init__(self):
          self.update_thread = threading. Thread(target=self.update)
          self.update_thread._stop_event = threading.Event()
          self.update_thread.start()

     def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
          # a lot of stuff going on here
          MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
          MainWindow.resize(400, 400)
          self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
          self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

     def update(self):
          # do something, not really relevant
          pass

     def closeEvent(self, event):
          print("test")
          self.update_thread._stop_event.set()
          self.update_thread.join()
          event.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
     import sys
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
     ui = Ui_MainWindow()
     ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
     MainWindow.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I left out the whole ui part, because it's just doing ... ui stuff.
What am I doing wrong here?

I am thankful for every suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's anything wrong in your code, but here's a version that works

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# UI Layout
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 872)


# Main window class
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("Close clicked")
        # Ask for confirmation
        answer = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self,
        "Confirm Exit...",
        "Are you sure you want to exit?\nAll data will be lost.",
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)

        event.ignore()
        if answer == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will rewrite my code, so that it works like yours.